# Склонение прилагательных сравнительной степени

Tags: морфология

Имеется слово "быстрее" - сравнительная степень от "быстрый"
Необходимо:
1) Определить, какая перед нами форма (кр. или полн.)
2) Определить тип склонения (адъективное, супплетивное, смешанное)

Comment: А что учебник говорит в отношении *кратких и полных форм для сравнительной степени*?)))

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что д/з

Answer (score 1):

А сами вы вообще ничего предполагать не хотите, верно? Прилагательное *быстрый* стоит в полной форме. Про склонение не совсем понял. Вы, верно, хотели спросить: «Как образовывается сравнительная степень у этого прилагательного?». Если это, то здесь просто прибавляется формообразующий суффикс *ее*, который как раз и позволяет нам образовать сравнительную степень многих прилагательных, например: медленный — медленнее, интересный — интереснее и т.д. Вижу, что вы о супплетивном методе начали говорить. Такое явление наблюдается в слове *хороший*. Сравнительная степень — *лучше* (видите, меняется основа полностью), лучший — превосходная степень.

Comment: Не надо решать за автора. Склонение сравнительной степени возможно, если под ней понимать аналитическую форму ("более быстрый"). Шут его знает, где он знаний нахватался.